# Можно ли удалять плагины Wordpress после завершения работы с ними

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Всем привет. Вот интересует данный вопрос. Например у меня есть плагин для оптимизации изображений ewww image optimizer, все картинки обработаны и он больше не нужен, можно ли его теперь удалить. 
Да, я понимаю что при загрузке новых изображений они не будут оптимизированы, но это меня не волнует. 
Главный вопрос можно ли это делать в принципе, после каких нибудь одноразовых операций когда плагин установил что-то сделал больше им не пользуешся

Comment: Можно конечно. Более того, часто даже нужно. Чем больше неиспользуемых плагинов установлено в CMS, тем больше котиков грустит во всём мире.

Answer (score 1):

> Главный вопрос можно ли это делать в принципе, после каких нибудь
>   одноразовых операций когда плагин установил что-то сделал больше им не
>   пользуешся

Нужно.
Но оч желательно удалять средствами ВП, а не просто каталог с хостинга. Правильно написанные плагины при этом убирают за собой и в базе.

Answer (score 1):

Если точно уверены что плагин не нужен - удаляйте. Но некоторые плагины не чистят за собой. А некоторые чистят и то что вы думаете должно остаться. Но это редкие исключения. В любом случае перед удаление делайте копию файлов и БД. И можно спокойно удалять. И как сказали выше удаляйте через кнопку удалить плагин. Правильно написанные плагины подчистят за собой и в БД и в файловой структуре где наследили.